# Assembly x86 NULL terminator (TASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

This program must simply read text from file and output it. The problem is that filename is entered by user.

***What I did so far:***

- I placed a zero terminator to indicate the end of the string
- And made a new text file in the exact folder where the .exe file is

***What I get:***

- File cannot be opened

  ```
      .model small

      .stack  100h 

      .data 
              filename    db 255 dup(0)
              line        db 255 dup(0)    

              filehandle  dw ?
              line_len    dw ?  

      .code 
              newline macro    ;NEW LINE 
                               ;
              mov dl, 10       ;
              mov ah, 02h      ;
                               ;
              int 21h          ;
                               ;
              mov dl, 13       ;
              mov ah, 02h      ;
                               ;
              int 21h          ;                
              endm             ;NEW LINE
      main:   

              mov ax, @data    
              mov ds, ax   

              lea si, filename
              mov ah, 01h 

      char_input:

              int 21h         

              cmp al, 0dh     
              je zero_terminator

              mov [si], al    
              inc si

              jmp char_input  

      zero_terminator:

              mov [si], '\0' 

              int 21h 

      open_file:

              lea dx, filename         
              mov al, 0          
              mov ah, 3Dh

              int 21h  

              mov filehandle, ax    

              int 21h

      read_line:

              mov ah, 3Fh     
              lea bx, filehandle             
              mov cx, 1              

              int 21h         

              cmp ax, 0       ;EOF            
              je EO_file  

              inc line_len

              jmp read_line:

      EO_file: 

              newline         ;macro

              lea dx, line    ;print line
              mov bx, 1       
              mov ah, 40h     
              mov cx, line_len

              int 21h         

              mov ah, 4ch 

              int 21h                

      end main
  ```

Comment: You have some extra `int 21h` calls for no apparent reason. As far as opening the file, it looks okay. Use a debugger to verify the file name is stored correctly and what the returned file handle is. Edit: make sure your assembler understands `'\0'`, or better yet, just write `0`.

Comment: Thanks, it works with 0 instead of '\0' now.

Comment: But sadly, It's stuck in read loop now... Program cannot find the end of file even if I check returned AX value

Comment: `lea bx, filehandle` should most probably be `mov bx, filehandle`, you want the handle not its address. You also forgot to specify the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing Jester's comments and adding a few remarks, here are the problems with your program:

```
zero_terminator:
mov [si], '\0'
int 21h
```

This `int 21h` instruction should be removed. Using '\0' will not zero terminate the filename. Better use a plain **0**.

```
mov filehandle, ax
int 21h
read_line:
```

This `int 21h` instruction should also be removed.

```
read_line:
mov ah, 3Fh
lea bx, filehandle
mov cx, 1
int 21h
```

In this read block you forgot to setup the buffer address in DX and you erroneously moved the address of the filehandle variable in BX where in fact you need its value. **Also note that the buffer address needs to increment with each iteration of this loop!** Change to:

```
lea dx, line
read_line:
mov ah, 3Fh
mov bx, filehandle
mov cx, 1
int 21h
;;; jc EO_file ??
cmp ax, 0       ;EOF            
je EO_file  
inc line_len
inc dx
jmp read_line   ; <-- Here you had a typo!
```

It would be great to check the CF after opening the file to confirm that indeed you got a valid handle.

Comment: And it would be great if you included attributions as required by the licensing :P

Comment: @Jester I added attributions for your commenting on this question.